# The controller for path '/' could not be found or it does not implement IController

Tags: webforms, asp.net-mvc-2, ext.net

I'm working on a Web Forms application and using EXT.NET framework for the views, i have a panel on the side with buttons that when i click on them, a view opens in a tab on the same page, like an iframe for the view

```
<Listeners>
      <ItemClick Handler="Fps.addTab({ title: menuItem.text, url: menuItem.url, icon: menuItem.iconCls });" />
</Listeners>
      <Items>
        <ext:MenuItem ID="MenuItem3" runat="server" Text="My Messages" Icon="Email">
             <CustomConfig>
                 <ext:ConfigItem Name="url" Value="../Message/MessageWindow" Mode="Value" AutoDataBind="true">
                            </ext:ConfigItem>
                            <ext:ConfigItem Name="passParentSize" Value="true" Mode="Raw">
                            </ext:ConfigItem>
                        </CustomConfig>
                    </ext:MenuItem>
    </Items>
```

Controller:

```
class MessageController : Controller
    {
        [HandleError]
        public ActionResult MessageWindow()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Whenever i click on it, it says The controller for path '/' could not be found or it does not implement IController.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

please add
public
before
class MessageController : Controller